# How to integrate Ascii-to-Svg with HUGO

Tags: go, svg, ascii, diagram, hugo

I am new to HUGO/GO so need basic example of generating SVG diagrams using [AsciiToSvg](https://github.com/asciitosvg/asciitosvg) in my static website.

I have imported the required module in `config.toml` as below, following [this article](https://www.thenewdynamic.com/article/hugo-modules-everything-from-imports-to-create/):

```
[[module.imports]]
path = "github.com/asciitosvg/asciitosvg"
```

But not sure how to proceed with generating an SVG diagram using `Ascii2Svg` for following text in my `markdown.md` file:

```
---
title: Home
---
.-------------------------.
|                         |
| .---.-. .-----. .-----. |
| | .-. | +-->  | |  <--| |
| | '-' | |  <--| +-->  | |
| '---'-' '-----' '-----' |
|  ascii     2      svg   |
|                         |
'-------------------------'
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Ascii2svg is a go module not a hugo module. If you want a function to generate such content - that's a point of changing the way Hugo renders, not just "loading a module".